# Openstack create volume via Nova API

Tags: api, volume, openstack, cinder

I'm trying to build a small webapp that will handle our development environments located on an openstack infrastructure (version 2012.2.2-dev, bundled in ubuntu 12.04) and I need to create some volumes using the API (i decided to use openstack rest api). I'm able to start machines and do some other operations (everything is built based on this: http://api.openstack.org/api-ref.html). If I send the request to create a volume as explained on the api reference, i get a 404. I tried different api versions (v1), but still no success.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you coding in? You could just use an SDK for this and skip trying to talk to the API directly. See

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/SDKs

Answer (score 1):

In newer releases of OpenStack it is preferable to make use of the Cinder API rather than Nova API.

In folsom, Cinder uses IDENTICAL API refs to Nova volume related API sets.  This is because this was the first release to separate out volume management to cinder as a stand alone project.  While volume API references remain in folsom it is not the default and it is not the preferred method for accessing volumes REST queries.

Check out.

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/cinder/